# Finding $\ \dim(N_1 \cap N_2) $ and proving $\ n \ge 2 $

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $\ V $ be a linear space over $\ F $, $\ \dim V = n $ and $\ T_1,T_2 : V \rightarrow F $ are linear transofrmations. $\ T_1 , T_2 \not = 0 , N_1 = \ker T_1 , N_2 = \ker T_2 $ and suppose $\ N_1 \not = N_2 $

Prove that $\ n \ge 2 $ and find $\ \dim(N_1 \cap N_2) $

So far what i've got is

$\ n = 0 \Rightarrow T_i = 0 $

$\ n = 1 $ and $\ T_1 , T_2 \not = 0 $ $\Rightarrow \ker T_1 = \ker T_2 $

therefore $\ n\ge 2 $

now $\ dim(N_1 \cap N_2) = \dim(N_1) + \dim(N_2) - dim(N_1 + N_2) $ and I know that $\ \dim N_i + \dim Im T_i = n $

and therefore $\ \dim(N_1) + \dim(N_2) = 2n - \dim Im T_1 - \dim ImT_2 $

So I get then $\ \dim(N_1 \cap N_2) = 2n - \dim ImT_1 - \dim imT_2 -dim(N_1 + N_2 )$

but I don't understand  how can I procceed from here if I'm correct so far?

Comment: Your calculations are correct. The question is what kind of equality do you want? I.e. why aren't you satisfied with what you got?

Comment: Because I need to find the $\ dim(N_1 \cap N_2) $ but looking again through the answers sheet it seems like the question is missing one important fact and it is that $\ \dim F = 1 $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the last comment which gives the additional condition $\dim(F)=1$, since $T_1,T_2\neq 0$, $\dim(\operatorname{img}(T_i))=1$ and $N_1+N_2=V$ which gives you $$\dim(N_1\cap N_2)=2n-2-n=n-2.$$

Comment: I must ask, something I am not sure about, is it always true that $\ \dim Im T + \dim \ker T = \dim V $ , could there be case where I have a linear transformation $\ T: V \rightarrow V $ such that $\ \dim Im T + \dim Ker T \le \dim V $ ?

Comment: This does never occur. The dimension formula is always an equality. A nice proof of this fact can be found e.g. on wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank–nullity_theorem#First_proof

Answer (score 1):

It easy to see that $\operatorname{Im} T_1 = \operatorname{Im} T_2 = F$ because $T_1,T_2 \neq 0$ and $F$ is of one dimension (the subspace of $F$ is either $F$ or 0). Therefore $$\operatorname{dim}N_1 = \operatorname{dim}N_2 = n-1.$$ Because $N_1 \neq N_2$, we have $N_1 + N_2 = V$. So $$\operatorname{dim}N_1 \cap N_2 = \operatorname{dim} N_1 +\operatorname{dim} N_2-\operatorname{dim} (N_1 + N_2) = (n-1)+(n-1)-n = n-2.$$